# How do I loop mount programmatically?

Tags: mount, c

I have recently written a [guide on how to mount partitions from image files on Raspberry Pi.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/855/86). The instructions are rather complicated and I have a bit of time, so want to replace them by [a C program](https://github.com/alexchamberlain/piimg). I have successfully listed the partitions of the image and calculated to appropriate offsets.

In the original instructions, we needed to run

```
$ sudo mount -o loop,offset=80740352 debian6-19-04-2012.img /mnt
```

I now need to do this in code. I have found the [mount](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mount) function and [libmount in util-linux](http://git.kernel.org/?p=utils/util-linux/util-linux.git;a=summary).

I have now found [loopdev.c](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/lib/loopdev.c) in util-linux. Is there an easy way to create loop devices or do I have to learn from this code and use ioctl?

Comment: Do you mean find the offset of the root partition in bytes?

Comment: I've calculated that - now I need to mount it.

Comment: Simplest by far is to call `mount` from your code (using `system` or an `exec*` variant).

Comment: Have you already seen the man pages for mount(2)? http://linux.die.net/man/2/mount or on what part exactly are you failing?

Comment: Why don't you write shell script?

Comment: @iblue I have a bit of time on my hands... I'm also more confident with C than Bash. Git was originally written in shell scripts and then ported, I guess I'm (stupidly?) missing out a step.

Comment: You can fork and exec the mount command from C, skipping the shell. It looks like it'll be easy. Your argv will have a few fixed strings, one user-supplied image filename, and one `sprintf(..., "loop,offset=%llu", offset)`

Comment: I'd ask the util-linux mailing list. Here is some info from the README. WEB PAGE:

     http://kernel.org/~kzak/util-linux/


MAILING LIST:

      E-MAIL: util-linux@vger.kernel.org
      URL:    http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#util-linux


DOWNLOAD:

      ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/


SOURCE CODE:

      Web interface:
          http://git.kernel.org/?p=utils/util-linux/util-linux.git
      Checkout:
          git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git util-linux

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: Is the `offset=80740352` the part that is giving you trouble?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Nope, if you look at my progress on [Github](https://github.com/alexchamberlain/piimg), you can see I am calculating offsets. Creating the loop device is a problem.

Comment: I think I have solved this in my head... I will post an answer once I've got code compiling.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following function binds the loop device `device` to `file` at `offset`. It returns 0 on success, 1 otherwise.

```
int loopdev_setup_device(const char * file, uint64_t offset, const char * device) {
  int file_fd = open(file, O_RDWR);
  int device_fd = -1; 

  struct loop_info64 info;

  if(file_fd < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open backing file (%s).\n", file);
    goto error;
  }

  if((device_fd = open(device, O_RDWR)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open device (%s).\n", device);
    goto error;
  }

  if(ioctl(device_fd, LOOP_SET_FD, file_fd) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to set fd.\n");
    goto error;
  }

  close(file_fd);
  file_fd = -1; 

  memset(&info, 0, sizeof(struct loop_info64)); /* Is this necessary? */
  info.lo_offset = offset;
  /* info.lo_sizelimit = 0 => max avilable */
  /* info.lo_encrypt_type = 0 => none */

  if(ioctl(device_fd, LOOP_SET_STATUS64, &info)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to set info.\n");
    goto error;
  }

  close(device_fd);
  device_fd = -1; 

  return 0;

  error:
    if(file_fd >= 0) {
      close(file_fd);
    }   
    if(device_fd >= 0) {
      ioctl(device_fd, LOOP_CLR_FD, 0); 
      close(device_fd);
    }   
    return 1;
}
```

#### References

1. [linux/loop.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/loop.h)
2. [piimg](https://github.com/alexchamberlain/piimg)